# Хранение пароля в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, password-hash

Всем привет. Такой вопрос, работаю с Apache Airflow, поднят в контейнерах. Так как стенд тестовый, то часто контейнеры приходится перестраивать (много косячим, приходится все откатывать). Вследствие этого слетают все настроенные соединения, постоянно добавлять их в веб-интерфейсе надоело, появилась задумка сделать баш или питон оператор, который будет добавлять эти соединения. Загвоздка в том, что для подсоединения к БД нужны логин и пароль, а хранить их в скрипте в открытом виде как то не секурно, а в интернете только безопасное хранение полученное от пользователя. Но у меня задача не чтобы при запуске скрипта самому вводить доступы (с таким раскладом я так же могу в веб интерфейсе все это вводить). А как то чтобы настройки соединения сами добавлялись, при этом логин/пароль не хранились в открытом виде в коде

Comment: Нет возможности прокинуть переменные окружения в контейнеры? Как в GitLab CI/CD, например.

Answer (score 1):

Ну как самый просто вариант, создать отдельный файл в той же директории а-ля config.py следующего содержания:

```
LOGIN = 'very_bad_login'
PASSWORD = 'very_secret_password'
```

После этого в искомом коде программы вначале добавить и затем использовать через переменные:

```
from config import LOGIN
from config import PASSWORD

login = LOGIN
passwd = PASSWORD
```

В качестве дополнения можно добавить защиту от shoulder surfing в виде импорта base64. Это всё, конечно, не совсем безопасно, но решает проблему прямого написания логина\пароля в конфиге.

Comment: Я думал сделать так, но просто подумал, что если доберутся до файла скрипта, то так же доберутся до файла config.py, лежащего в той папке, но да, при просмотре кода (который отображается в веб-морде) логин с паролем фигурировать не будут, а так как скрипты находятся в защищенной сети, то защита приемлемая выходит

Comment: Ну тогда может вообще создать две переменных с вычисленным хэшем от логина и пароля и всунуть одну def() c вычислением хэша от введеных данных. Тогда просто вводится логин пароль (если через getpass()), то опять же его никто не увидит, они сравнятся с значением хэша и код начнёт исполнение.

Comment: это я читал, проблема в том, что как раз логин и пароль каждый раз вводить не хочется. Пользователь в данном случае я, просто не хочется вводить это каждый раз. Когда доступы вводит пользователь, исходные открытые данные он хранит условно у себя в голове, я же хотел узнать, есть ли возможность секурно логин/пароль хранить где то на локальном компе

Comment: Я, конечно, не знаю что и зачем вы делаете, однако почти всё, что напрямую хранит логин\пароль уже не является безопасным. Относительно безопасно, можно сказать - это хэш, еще лучше с солью. А, например, импорт как я написал в ответе в сумме с base64 - это обычная защита от рядового юзера.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.